# A variable is spontaneously growing when I attempt to assign it to a list index

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, byte

Essentially, I have a list of hashes. I need to modify each one slightly by inserting a section of the hash in front of it. A bit random, I admit, but all of the main code works fine.

```
import hashlib

bytes_to_hash = b"this is an interesting bytes object"
cycles = 65
digest_length = 10000

hash_list = [
hashlib.shake_256(bytes_to_hash).digest(digest_length),
hashlib.shake_256(bytes_to_hash + b"123").digest(digest_length)
]

for _ in range(cycles):
    number = 0 #will be used to generate the next hash later on

    for x in range(4):
        selection = int(hashlib.sha256(hash_list[-1] + str(x).encode()).hexdigest(), 16) % digest_length
        #^ used to pseudorandomly select a number

        for count, hash in enumerate(hash_list):
            number += hash[selection]

            prev_hash = hash_list[count - 1]
            prev_hash = prev_hash[:selection - 512] + hash[selection - 512 : selection] + prev_hash[selection:]

            #hash_list[count - 1] = prev_hash
            #^ this is the issue

    number = number % digest_length
    selection_range = hash_list[-1][number - 128 : number]

    hash_list.append(hashlib.shake_256(selection_range).digest(digest_length))
```

The problem comes when I attempt to actually modify the list itself. This simple line screws everything up -

```
            hash_list[count - 1] = prev_hash
```

After adding this line, the script suddenly takes a very long time of to execute, up from about 75 ms to over 100 seconds. A sanity check of removing that line and inserting `print(len(prev_hash))` proved that the length of `prev_hash` is always 10,000, exactly what I expected. It is only when I attempt to assign `prev_hash` to a list index that the length reaches as high as 19,000,000 for no apparent reason. The weirdest part is that after reintroducing that line, it seems that the length of `prev_hash` *itself* is what's actually expanding, not the value in the list.

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, any help is appreciated.

Comment: In general, modifying a list *while you're actively iterating over it* is something you want to avoid.  It can lead to lots of problems.  You'd be better off constructing a new list, then replacing the old list with the new one *after* the loop exits.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that the first time through the loop, `count` is `0`, so `count - 1` is `-1`, which means you're assigning to the *last* element of `hash_list`.  Is this intentional?  It seems like it might be a bug.

Comment: Also, you're creating multiple slices of the list each time through, and concatenating them, which is likely to be very slow.  Are you certain you need to do that?

Comment: @TomKarzes Ah, good point. I'll try creating another list from scratch and see where that gets me.

Comment: @TomKarzes and yeah, the looping is intentional.

For the other thing you mentioned though, I'm not entirely sure what you mean. My best guess is that you're asking if I intend to be repeating the same action many times over (correct me if I'm wrong), in which case yes that is intentional.